# Variables inside commands inside if statement

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, environment-variables, bash-scripting

I do not understand why this does not work:

```
existing_user=$(ldapsearch -x -b "cn=group,ou=group2,dc=company,dc=com" -H ldap://127.0.0.1 -D "cn=admin,dc=company,dc=com" -w "Password" cn uid | grep "uid: $username")
echo $existing_user
```

Why cant I use a positional paramter inside a variable?

I am trying this (simplified):

```
variable1=$(some command | grep "user: $1")
echo $variable1
```

As if he does not read a variable inside another variable?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is there a particula reason you're calling `$()` instead of just using `()`? Your example doesn't include any value for `$username` so it's not surprising that it would be undefined.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you should put linux commands into $( ), right?
Yes, I do not have variable for user: $1 because that is a positional parametar,meaning I will create it once I deploy the script: 

./script.sh $user1

Comment: That would be the case if you actually did run it that way but your example actually does include `$username` it won't magically make `$username` equal to `$1`.